# Can I run on specific host or group of hosts in a Ansible task?

Tags: ansible

Can I run on specific host or group of hosts in a Ansible task?

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Disable tuned
      hosts: client1.local
      service:
        name: tuned
        enabled: false
        state: stopped
```

It does not work anyway. Here is the error:

```
[root@centos7 ansible]# ansible-playbook playbook/demo.yaml
ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, service

The error appears to be in '/root/ansible/playbook/demo.yaml': line 24, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Disable tuned
  ^ here
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12,test_13
  vars:
    client1:
      showroom: [test11, test12]
      local: [test_13]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
    - debug:
        msg: "Local client: {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in client1.local
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_11
ok: [test_12] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_12
ok: [test_13] => 
  inventory_hostname: test_13

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
skipping: [test_11]
skipping: [test_12]
ok: [test_13] => 
  msg: 'Local client: test_13'
```

Answer (score 0):

### You need a tailor-made `when:` clause.

Beware that [`when:` clauses have quoting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50658222).

For a single host:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Disable tuned
      when: >-
        inventory_hostname == "this-one-host"
      service:
        name: tuned
        enabled: false
        state: stopped
```

For multiple hosts:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Disable tuned
      when: >-
        inventory_hostname in _run_only_on
      vars:
        _run_only_on:
          - host1
          - host2
      service:
        name: tuned
        enabled: false
        state: stopped
```

For a group (using the [`group_names` special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-group_names)):

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Disable tuned
      when: >-
        "some_group" in group_names
      service:
        name: tuned
        enabled: false
        state: stopped
```